# pyspark and pytorch: unable to retrieve gradients on the driver

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch and I'm trying to explore the feasibility of its usage with spark (for now I'm working in spark standalone).

As for now I'm struggling on a very specific topic.
Let's start with a very simple model:

```
# linmodel.py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np

def standardize(x):
    return (x - np.mean(x)) / np.std(x)

def add_noise(y):
    rnd = np.random.randn(y.shape[0])
    return y + rnd

def cost(target, predicted):
    cost = torch.sum((torch.t(target) - predicted) ** 2)
    return cost

class LinModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_size, out_size):
        super(LinModel, self).__init__()  # always call parent's init
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_size, out_size, bias=False)  # layer parameters

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)
```

Which instantiates a basic linear model, along with some utility functions.
The goal is to approximate a target matrix, and to keep track of how the
gradients behave.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. create my target matrix
2. split the inputs on the workers
3. instantiate models and optimizer on the workers
4. compute the approximation on subsets of input
5. retrieve the gradients for further analysis

And everything works fine until point 5.
Here's the code:

```
#test.py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import torch.optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
from pyspark import SparkContext
import linmodel

def prepare_input(nsamples=400):
   Xold = np.linspace(0, 1000, nsamples).reshape([nsamples, 1])
   X = linmodel.standardize(Xold)
   W = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(5, 1))
   Y = W.dot(X.T)  # target
   for i in range(Y.shape[1]):
      Y[:, i] = linmodel.add_noise(Y[:, i])
   x = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X), requires_grad=False).type(torch.FloatTensor)
   y = Variable(torch.from_numpy(Y), requires_grad=False).type(torch.FloatTensor)
   print("created torch variables {} {}".format(x.size(), y.size()))
   return x, y, W

def initialize(tup):
    x, y = tup[0]   # data
    m, o = tup[1]   # model and optimizer
    model, optimizer = torch_step(x, y, m, o)
    # here we have the gradients
    print('gradient: {}'.format([param.grad.data for param in model.parameters()]))  
    return (x, y), (model, optimizer)

def create_model():
    model = linmodel.LinModel(1, 5)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
    return model, optimizer

def torch_step(x, y, model, optimizer):
    prediction = model(x)
    loss = linmodel.cost(y, prediction)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    return model, optimizer

def main(sc, num_partitions=4):
    x, y, W = prepare_input()
    parts_x = list(torch.split(x, int(x.size()[0] / num_partitions)))
    parts_y = list(torch.split(y, int(x.size()[0] / num_partitions), 1))
    rdd_models = sc.parallelize([create_model() for _ in range(num_partitions)]).repartition(num_partitions)

    rdd_x = sc.parallelize(parts_x).repartition(num_partitions)
    rdd_y = sc.parallelize(parts_y).repartition(num_partitions)
    parts = rdd_x.zip(rdd_y)  # [((100x1), (5x100)), ...]
    full = parts.zip(rdd_models).map(initialize).cache()

    models_out = full.map(lambda x: x[1][0]).collect()
    test_model = models_out[0]
    print(type(test_model))
    print('gradient: {}'.format([param.grad.data for param in test_model.parameters()]))  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext(appName='test')
    main(sc)
```

As you can see in the comments , when the function `initialize` is mapped on the full rdd, if you inspect the logs of the executors you'll find the gradients to be computed.
When I collect the result and try to access the very same attribute on the driver I receive a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'`
meaning that all the `model.grad` attribute are set to `None`.

I'm sure I'm missing something big here, but I cannot see it.

Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like the cannot be fully serialized. Common problem, if you use objects which depend on native code.

Comment: Yes. You're right. Tried `torch.save`, `json` and `pickle`. No luck. Better proceed in other direction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I might be wrong, but `save` / `load` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major mistakes in your approach (according to me):

1. Since you want a distributed training, your approach of instantiating the model separately in all of the executors is wrong. You should instantiate the model in the head node (node where spark driver is located) and then distribute that model to all the executors. So each executor independently does forward pass and calculates the gradients on its portion of data and passes the gradients to the head node for weight update (weight update has to be serialized). Then the updated network is again `scattered` to the executors for the next iteration.
2. A much bigger concern is that I am not very sure if the gradient buffers are copied to the head node from the executors when you perform `.collect()`. Due to which `model.grad` can be set to `None`. To begin debugging, I suggest you have only one executor (and 1 partition) and then perform a `.collect()` to see if the gradient buffers are being copied. Or if you are good at Java or Scala, you can look at the `collect()` method's implementation.

Hope this helps.....